# Should RBS be used when storing 3TB files on on-premises SPS 2019?

Tags: rbs

When I built SPS2013, I used to choose RBS.
Now if there are use cases where you have to choose RBS in the situation where the specifications of SQL Server and hardware are rising, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

No. RBS was designed for migrating from Windows Internal Database on WSSv3 to SharePoint 2010 Foundation with SQL Express. WID did not have a cap on how much binary data it contains where as SQL 2008 Express had a 4GB MDF size limit.

RBS doesn't increase performance with a properly implemented SQL Server and significantly increases complexity of maintenance and disaster recovery.